# how to plot x and y based on several conditions?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe, constructed as follows:

```
col1<-c(0.10, 0.21, 0.34, 0.39, 0.54, 0.67,0.89)
col2<-c (0,100,500,1000,3000,5000,8000 )
col3<-c ("b", "a","a","c", "c","b",  "c" )
mydata<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

    > mydata
      col1   col2 col3
 #   1 0.10    0    b
 #   2 0.21   100   a
 #   3 0.34   500   a
 #   4 0.39  1000   c
 #   5 0.54  3000   c
 #   6 0.67  5000   b
 #   7 0.89  8000   c
```

here is my code to create a plot between `col2` and `col1`:

```
plot(mydata$col2,mydata$col1,
     main = "plot of my data",
     xlab = "x", ylab= "y",
     pch =c(21,21,21)[mydata$col3], bg=c("blue","grey", "red")[mydata$col3], 
)
legend("topright",pch=c(21,21,21), title="categories:",
       c("a","b", "c"),pt.bg=c("blue","red","grey"))
```

it creates the plot:

[image]

I have problems in my codes:

1, There should be 7 points in the plot, but one has been covered by the topright box. Is there any better method to get all the points display?

2, I want to have different scales in x-axis to label tick marks with desired interval, like [image: plot 2]. See that the interval between 100 and 500 is almost the same as 3000 and 8000, so the smaller values are not suppressed extremely to the left side, that is what I want. How to achieve that?

3, It seems that in my syntax `pch =c(21,21,21)[mydata$col3], bg=c("blue","grey", "red")[mydata$col3]`, I haven't specified which colour maps to "a", "b" or "c". If I want to respectively map colours `"blue","grey", "red"` to `"a", "b" and "c"` given in the `col3`. How to specify it?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: for 1, why not move your legend to the bottom?

Comment: For the first, just adjust the position of  your legend, try `legend("topleft", ...)`, or if you want the legend to be placed outside the plot, try use `par(xpd=TRUE)`, and then `legend(x,y,...)`, where you can choose different values of x and y to place the legend

Comment: in what way does `c("blue","grey","red")[mydata$col3]` not map "blue","grey", "red" to "a", "b" and "c"?

Comment: Thanks @rawr. Since I haven't specify which colour map to which value in col3, I think it is not logical that `c("blue","grey","red")[mydata$col3]` indicates "blue","grey", "red"  mapping to "a", "b" and "c"

Comment: but it does.. it works doesn't it?

Comment: Yes @rawr, but I think it is coincidence, because it is not always the case when I use the same syntax to another dataset.

Comment: @rawr. Yes it would work in this case, because the `col3` has value a, b and c, which allows the color to be assigned based on the order of the values. But this could be annoying when you have  '5a','2b','3c' as the values, if you still want to assign colors "blue", "grey", "red" to '5a','2b','3c', the assignment should based on the order of these values, which is c("grey","red","blue")[mydata$col3]. Mapping is a safe way to assign the colors

Comment: @eclo.qh then post another question with that example and I will show you how it does work every time and not just a "coincidence."

Comment: @Conta yes I know all of that. It is not annoying at all. you simply need to know how factors work which is also a simple idea

Comment: Thanks @rawr. Since my actual dataset is too large, and it has a lot of codes to reach that dataframe to create the plot, it is not that suitable to post it here. If you like, it would be better to transfer to email or other tool to send the datafile and code for you to check for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, you could use a customize axis. In your case, you want to customize the x axis. So in the `plot` function, you need to add `xaxt="n"`, which disable the original x axis. Then you could use `axis` to add yours. In your case, try

```
axis(1, at=c(a,b,c,d,e),labels=c(a,b,c,d,e),xxx,xxx)
```

where a, b,c,d,e are the values you want to have.

Example:

```
y <- x <- c(1:5)
plot(x, y,type="l", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=c(1,1.3,1.5,1.7,2.8),labels=c(1,1.3,1.5,1.7,2.8))
```

[image]

For the third question, how about just adding a column of mapping colors to the `dataframe`? As following:
For instance,

```
 mydata$color <-ifelse(mydata$col3=="a","blue",ifelse(mydata$col3=="b","red","grey"))
```

which maps a with color blue, b with color red and c with grey. And in the plot,

```
plot(mydata$col2,mydata$col1,xxxxxx, bg=mydata$color,  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Conta. I add `xaxt="n"` in the `plot()` function, and a syntax `axis(1, at=c(0,100,500,1000),labels=c(0,100,500,1000))` is added, but it doesn't create an `0,100,500,1000` at the x-axis. Any other advice?

Comment: @eclo.qh, did it create an x axis for you?

Comment: Thanks @Conta, I saw your update, but it is still a problem that not all the tick marks are labelled as desired. It is still a problem to be solved.

Comment: @eclo.qh, I guess it is because your range of x is too large relative to your marks. I tried with your example, only when I maximize the plot, I can see the mark 0, 500 and 1000.

Comment: @eclo.qh, if you do not mind, try adding the option `las=2` in the `axis(...)`, which could display the marks perpendicularly to the x-axis

Comment: but I think it is not the problem with the range of x. I think it is allowwed to have different scale in the same X-axis, but I just don't know how to do.

Comment: Thanks @Conta. It's a better alternative, but it is not desired. I still need to solve this problem.

Comment: don't use nested ifelse, the original way done by OP is so much better

Comment: @eclo.qh It does allow to have different scales, I think the ticks are all plotted, the problem is not all labels show up. This is because the interval between two marks is too small relative to the range of x-axis, so the `plot` function have no space to write two labels.

Comment: Thanks @Conta. Maybe my description is not that correct. Have you see the plot 2 in my question? What I actually want is to display the tick mark 100, 500, 6000, 8000 or else in the axis. See that 100 and 500 is far smaller than 8000, but when I label it in the x-axis, I want that it is not suppressed to the extreme left side. So it seems they have different sale.

Comment: @eclo.qh. I see what your problem. I think it is not just simple as the `axis` problem, since you want to the corresponding points to be scaled as well, right?

Comment: Yes @Conta, I have updated my description for that question. The distances between points at the X-axis has changed, cuze smaller values has almost the same interval with larger value. So the distribution of the points should have smaller change in the X-scale.

Comment: @eclo.qh, a tricky approach, scale your `col2`, the original is `c(0,100,500,1000,3000,5000,8000 )`, you can change it into `col2<-c (0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,8000 )`, then in the `axis()`, you can specify it as `axis(1,at=c(1000,2000,6000,8000),labels=c("100","500","6000","8000"),las=1)`. This would show you '100', '500' not located extremely at left side

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience @Conta .Since it is an exercise given my R professor, I think change the original dataframe is not what he desires.

Comment: @eclo.qh. Sure. How about `plot(1:length(unique(mydata$col2)),mydata$col1,xxxxx)`, and 
`axis(1, at=1:length(unique(mydata$col2)), labels = c(unique(mydata$col2)), las=2)`. This does not change the original `data.frame`, but did a scale function as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100871/discussion-between-eclo-qh-and-conta).

Answer (score 1):

For 3, if you don't mind installing the `plyr` package, you can use `mapvalues()` function. In your case, it would be `bg=as.character(mapvalues(mydata$col3, from=c("a", "b", "c"), to=c("blue", "grey", "red")))`. The function `as.character()` here is because the output of `mapvalues()` is a factor. Also you can change the `col3` in your dataframe to be character first, then the output of `mapvalues()` would be character. If you don't want to install new packages, you can use `levels(mydata$col3) <- c("blue", "grey", "red")` to change the `col3`'s levels.